# Modify the minimum height of ListItem in Jetpack Compose Material 3

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material3

The minimum height of `ListItem` in Material 3 is `56.0.dp`.

`minHeight = ListTokens.ListItemContainerHeight,`

How can I change this height?

Comment: Use a custom Row instead of ListItem

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti not a good way

Comment: The minHeight is hardcoded, you can't override it.

Comment: yes, maybe we need to rewrite